# .net core edit view being submitted itself twice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a very basic controller which does some getting of information. When I land on this view it's automatically submitting the form twice and as a result the code breaks. I am not using javascript to post the form. I have tried javascipt to prevent form submit but not working.

```
        [HttpGet]
    //[PreventDuplicateFormSubmissionAttribute]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {
        var RulePlanViewModel = new RulePlanViewModel();
        var EditRulePlanCustomModel = new EditRulePlanCustomModel();
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.RulePlanViewModel = new RulePlanViewModel();
        await using var connection = Connection.GetOpenConnection(_config.GetConnectionString("BetterCompareStagingLatest"));
        var query = string.Format(@"SELECT 
                                        UWRP.ID,
                                        UWRP.CreateDate,
                                        UWRP.CreateBy,
                                        UWLR.RuleName,
                                        UWLR.ID RuleID,
                                        UWLP.ID PlanID,
                                        UWLP.PlanName
                                    FROM uw_D_RulePlans UWRP
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN uw_L_Rules UWLR ON UWLR.ID = UWRP.RuleID
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN uw_L_Plan UWLP ON UWLP.ID = UWRP.PlanID WHERE UWRP.ID = @id");
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.RulePlanViewModel = connection.Query<RulePlanViewModel>(query, new { id = id }).FirstOrDefault();


        var query2 = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM uw_L_Plan");
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_PlanList = new List<uw_L_Plan>();
        var data2 = connection.Query<uw_L_Plan>(query2).ToList();
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_PlanList = data2;

        var query3 = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM uw_L_Rules");
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_RulesList = new List<uw_L_Rules>();
        var data3 = connection.Query<uw_L_Rules>(query3).ToList();
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_RulesList = data3;

        EditRulePlanCustomModel.PlansDDL = new SelectList(EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_PlanList, "ID", "PlanName", EditRulePlanCustomModel.RulePlanViewModel.PlanID);
        EditRulePlanCustomModel.RulesDDL = new SelectList(EditRulePlanCustomModel.uw_L_RulesList, "ID", "RuleName", EditRulePlanCustomModel.RulePlanViewModel.RuleID);
        return View(EditRulePlanCustomModel);
    }
```

My view logic is such:

```
@model VCS.Underwriting.Models.EditRulePlanCustomModel
<div class="content container-fluid">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="js-select2-custom custom-select" size="1" style="opacity: 0;" asp-for="RulePlanViewModel.RuleID" asp-items="Model.RulesDDL"
                        data-hs-select2-options='{
                                                "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity",
                                                "placeholder": "Select Rule"
                                                }'>
                    <option label="empty"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select class="js-select2-custom custom-select" size="1" style="opacity: 0;" asp-for="RulePlanViewModel.PlanID" asp-items="Model.PlansDDL"
                        data-hs-select2-options='{
                                                "minimumResultsForSearch": "Infinity",
                                                "placeholder": "Select Rule"
                                                }'>
                    <option label="empty"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.RulePlanViewModel.ID" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please tell us about the details of `[PreventDuplicateFormSubmissionAttribute]` this middleware? Does it called when you load the view? In addition, the view you have shared, is it `edit view` if so then where is the `index view` from where the `edit page` is redirected to. Another point is have you checked the `jquery-unobtrusive` referece in your project?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you may have multiple **jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js** placed in your application. You must have to make sure it loaded a single time. Either keep it in _layout.cshtml or you can add it on your view.

These scripts are by default included in _layout.cshtml view so if you include them again in child view it will cause it to post form twice